# Seperate Razor Pages Mobile - Desktop

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, razor-pages

How can I separate mobile and desktop pages in ASP.NET core? What's the best approach?

I have two pages like this

- /Home/Home.cshtml
- /Home/HomeMobile.cshtml

And these html files use same page directive

> @page "/home"

I tried a middleware but I don't know whether this is the best way? Is there the best approach?

```
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
{
    var userAgent = context.Request.Headers["User-Agent"].ToString();

    var dd = new DeviceDetector(userAgent);
    dd.Parse();

    var isMobile = dd.IsMobile();

    var routeData = context.GetRouteData();
    if (isMobile)
    {
        context.Response.Redirect("/Mobile");
    }
    else
    {
        context.Response.Redirect("/Desktop");
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you considered making your pages responsive to a range of screen sizes?

Comment: Sadly, ıt's not suitable for me. I might apply different component for mobile version.

Answer (score 1):

As @Crowcoder says, the best approach is NOT to have separate versions of the same content but to use `@media` queries to create a
[responsive design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design) for your pages so that they suit devices of all sizes. This approach replaced device detection some time ago, because the device detection approach requires that the libraries used to detect the device are kept up to date (which turned out not to be practical) and maintaining multiple versions of the same page is not productive.

A number of UI frameworks exist that focus on delivering responsive design. [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/) is the most popular one.

Comment: Sadly, it's not suitable for me. I might apply different component for mobile version. By the way I use Tailwind and there is bootstrap component also and It gives me more freedom.